# req.cookies from apollo-server-micro return empty object

Tags: node.js, next.js, apollo-server, next-auth

I couldn't get `req.cookies`, even `req.headers` as it return empty object and undefined.

I tried `'request.credentials'` value with `include` and `same-origin`, both not working.

I can get `req.cookies` from `getServerSideProps` but I don't want do this on every pages or create a HOF for this.

So, the question is why `req.cookies` in `context` is empty object?

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import Cors from 'micro-cors';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async (ctx) => {
    const token = await getToken({req: ctx.req, secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET})

    return {};
  },
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'request.credentials': 'include'
    }
  },
});

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ['POST', 'OPTIONS']
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

export default cors(
  server.createHandler({
    path: '/api/graphql'
  })
);
```